# Who Chooses the Amounts in The Chase?

Tags: the-chase

In the UK TV show The Chase the contestants answer questions to get a starting sum of money. The chaser then offers them a low and high offer. In the episode I just saw the contestant answered six questions and so got £6000 and got a low and high offer of £600 / £36,000. Their choice gives them more or advantage over the chaser.

A similar format is used in Beat the Chasers, the higher budget chaser team based show.

I don't believe the Chasers are free to just offer any amount of money on a whim. Who decides how much to offer the contestants and how is this communicated to the chaser?

Comment: Your example shows simple factors of ten under & six over. i don't watch the show, but you could check how much leeway there is in this spread, or whether it's always the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's definitely not a simple fixed formula; in particular then the low offer will occasionally even be negative.

Comment: OK, no probs. I did say I didn't watch it...

Answer (score 1):

I think the producers of the show give the chasers an upper limit of what they can say for the high offer, and the chaser decides on what they actually offer.

In the german version of the show, there [was a moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHhCEVbf6Y) when the chaser gives 60.000€, and when the contestant hesitates, the amount is changed to 100.000€ by the producers.